# What Shopify uses to minimize JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: shopify, minify

My test site has a huge loading time and test shows I can cut performance by minifying JS and CSS assets.

What Shopify uses to minimize JavaScript and CSS?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a quick google search first? Also, by the sounds of it, minifying your files won't fix your problem. Minifying will only shave off a small load time, useful for optimisation, and by the sounds of it this is something happening in your script to warrant a "huge loading time".

Comment: yes, I google searched it.

Comment: I tested it with many different solutions and the main issue was file sizes.
Also, I asked out of curiousity, I wanted to kjnow what Shopiffy uses and I couldn't find it official doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shopify doesn't have the ability to auto-minify your Javascript (you need to do that yourself), but it does have the ability to auto-minify your CSS by giving it an 'scss' suffix, then including it in your site with the suffix `.scss.css`

So if your CSS file is currently named `theme.css.liquid` and included in your site with `{{ 'theme.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`:

- Change the name of your CSS file to end with `.scss` (or `.scss.liquid`, if the file in question ends with `.css.liquid`) - so in this case, the file becomes `theme.scss.liquid`
- Change the reference to the file to end in `.scss.css` - so in this case, the include becomes  `{{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}` (Note that a `.liquid` suffix, if any, is not included here)

The result will be a minified CSS file built from your un-minified source code.

As John Bell mentions in a comment to your main post, though, minification alone probably won't resolve the underlying problems.  If you look at the waterfall results from your speed test, look for files that have a long 'Waiting' or 'TTFB' time - those are files that are taking a long time for Shopify to compile, and indicate that your Liquid code is what needs to be optimized.  Also look for files with a long 'Downloading' time, and see if those files could be compressed or only deferred so that they only load after the initial page has completed.

Comment: thanks, great to know that, so I minify before uploading

Comment: For javascript, that's the only way to get minified code with Shopify, correct :)

Comment: Also, if you have extremely large javascript files, it may make sense chunk them out into a few smaller files.  With HTTP/2 becoming mainstream, multiple smaller files are sometimes better than singular monoliths.  See for example the analysis at https://medium.com/@asyncmax/the-right-way-to-bundle-your-assets-for-faster-sites-over-http-2-437c37efe3ff

Comment: As of 8/12/2021 Shopify DOES auto-minify JS files: https://shopify.dev/changelog/shopify-now-serves-minified-javascript-files-automatically